# what mean range.hyperlink(1).address = range.value

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

what mean

```
range.hyperlink(1).address = range.value
```

Comment: What's the rest of your code? That line looks like it has some typos/errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it is `Hyperlinks` (plural) then `Range.Hyperlinks…` needs to specify a range address like `Range("A1").Hyperlinks…`. Same for `Range.Value`.

So either

```
Range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).Address = Range("A1").Value
```

or

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("A1")

Rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address = Rng.Value
```

#### So now what does it do?

It takes the first hyperlink that exists in the specified range eg `Range("A1")` and changes the URL of that hyperlink to the Value in that cell `A1`.

#### Be careful when you copy hyperlink cells

But be careful if you create a hyperlink eg in `A1` and copy the whole cell into a range (more than one cell) `A2:A10` the new inserted links will refer to the exact same hyperlink object, because the hyperlink object is only duplicated once (per inserted range) but not once (per inserted cell)! So in `A2:A10` all cells now reference the same hyperlink object.

> You can check that by using `Cells.Hyperlinks.Count` it will show `2` as result even if you see 10 hyperlinks in cells `A1:A10`.

That means if you then run

```
Range("A2").Hyperlinks(1).Address = Range("A2").Value
```

not only the URL of the hyperlink in `A2` changes but the URL of the hyperlinks in `A3:A10` are changed to the value of cell `A2` too, because it is the exact same hyperlink object (they share).

To get distinct hyperlink objects in each cells `A2:A10` you need to copy `A1` and insert one by one each cell eg. paste in `A2` then `A3` then `A4` …
This way for every pasted cell a unique hyperlink object is created.